# Working with bootstrap in open source LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css, bootstrap, open-source

I am currently exploring Open Source LWC and in my index.html I have below tags to use bootstrap

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-9/reFTGAW83EW2RDu2S0VKaIzap3H66lZH81PoYlFhbGU+6BZp6G7niu735Sk7lN"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css"
    integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"
    integrity="sha384-B4gt1jrGC7Jh4AgTPSdUtOBvfO8shuf57BaghqFfPlYxofvL8/KUEfYiJOMMV+rV"
    crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

now if I use

```
<div class="p-4"></div>
```

this works as expected in index.html but if I use the same div in my app.html then it doesn't work, could someone please help me to understand if we need to do something in LWC component to use third party CSS referenced in index.html.

Comment: I wonder if you could share a fuller example? I'm currently using Bootstrap styles in OSS LWC with no issues, but I'm not sure how to answer this one without seeing more.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, in open source LWC](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316879/mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-in-open-source)

Answer (score 2):

Try to use

```
import '@lwc/synthetic-shadow';
```

in your index.js

Comment: How does this answer the question asked here?

Comment: @AdrianLarson it switches on synthetic-shadow and provides the ability to use bootstrap css

Answer (score 0):

Temporarily solved this issue as mentioned in this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/316879/mime-type-text-html-is-not-a-supported-stylesheet-mime-type-in-open-source/316881#316881)

but if anyone has any better solution, then please do post the same here.