# MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, in open source LWC

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, css, html

Below is my file structure in open source LWC

[image]

in my index.html I am trying to reference bootstrap as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

but when page loads on localhost, i get below on the console log.

```
localhost/:1 Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:3001/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.
```

I also tried

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

or

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

I have also tried above all combinations with type="text/css" and type="css"

error remains same with type="text/css" and with type="css" error goes but not able to use any bootstrap class.

tried with and without crossorigin="anonymous"

there are similar questions already posted but the same answers don't work, please let me know what am I missing.

below is my css folder.

[image: css folder]

Answer (score 1):

this is weird, I cut paste CSS folder from bootstrap to resources folder and changed

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

to

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="./resources/css/bootstrap.css">
```

and it is working for index.html but to make it work for app.html I have added the below constructor in the app.js

for the time being it is working as mentioned in the this [thread](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/264196/lightning-web-components-lwc-open-source-site-css-file)

```
constructor() {

    super();
    const styles = document.createElement('link');
    styles.href = './resources/css/bootstrap.css';
    styles.rel = 'stylesheet';
    this.template.appendChild(styles);
}
```

Comment: While I understand this is the only possible workaround at the moment, modifying the DOM in constructor is a bad practice in LWC [Check out: developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/…. Shouldn't this be done in connectedCallback or renderedCallback instead?

Comment: Would you please share the link again, it is not working

Comment: Sorry, I missed to check the URL in my comments. Here you go, its in the LWC developer guide: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/create_lifecycle_hooks_created

Comment: yes this suggests connected callback, thank you for pointing it out